# Why is it not possible for equipotential surfaces to intersect in this case?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

My textbook reads
“ Two equipotential surfaces can never intersect because if they did, at the point of intersection, the field would have to have two directions (perpendicular to each surface) which is clearly absurd..”

I understand the fact that if there were to be a non-zero field at each point of the surface then since the surface is equipotential the Field must be perpendicular to the surface at each point.

But, is it also not possible that the field be zero throughout the two surfaces somehow?

In that case, considering the fact that the surfaces must have the same potential . According to me, the argument given in my textbook does not refute such a case.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/375514/50583

Comment: The question is similar, but the answer seems to be way above my level right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where the electric field at every point on two intersecting equipotential surfaces is zero, both of those equipotential surfaces are considered a single equipotential surface rather than two, since the potential at all the points on both the surfaces is the same. The potential on both the surfaces is the same because the work done in moving a unit charge from one point to another on the *combined equipotential surface* is zero since the electric field is zero.

So, **no**. This isn't a case where two equipotential surfaces *intersect* because there aren't two equipotential surfaces at all. It's just a single surface.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim? E.g. two straight planes intersecting is not conventionally called a "surface" in most contexts. See [Emilio's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/375717/50583) to a similar question for how to think about intersecting surfaces formally.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I suppose the formal/mathematical treatment was unneeded here (and was also out of my scope). This answer also asserts the same final results as Emilio's answer does. Two intersecting planes is just a generic example for any two intersecting surfaces.